# Get all items for a CSGO with steam web api

Tags: steam-web-api

I'm wondering if there's a way to retrieve all the active items names via the Steam API ?

I know you can check the prices per item, but is there a way to fetch every items names ?

Thanks

Comment: @ Alexandre Beadet,
Do you mean by "get all item names from CSGO" for an active user or in general?

Comment: @DanielElmnas I mean in general, like the full list of items (weapons in that case) existing in the game ! Thanks for taking the time to read and answer, really appreciate !

Comment: Hi again Alexandre,

To be honest I am very unsure if you able to make that with steams own API I been looking around.

Comment: @DanielElmnas Yup on the official doc couldn't find anything... The idea was to make a price analyst but the request need the full item name; and I wasn't feeling like making a 200 elements array to store them ! But if there's no solution guess I'll go with it ! Thanks for the time you took

Comment: @Alexande, I believe you can do it if you choose another provider to fetch that data. I seen that on site also on other git hub API:s

Comment: @DanielElmnas I guess that's the only way, seems to often be not-free but yeah... Thanks again mate !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, now you have got an answer how to continue your journey =)

anyway when I have developed different small sites/modules for steam,
I found these API:s very handy below:

[CSGO-Market (NPMJS)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csgo-market)
[CSGO-Stats](http://csgo-stats.com/)
[Steamspy](http://steamspy.com/api.php)
[CSGO-Backpack](http://csgobackpack.net/api/)
[Bitskins](https://bitskins.com/api)

I hope this will help you!

have a nice day

Regards

Daniel

Comment: Wow that's actually a lot of APIs, I'm sure I'll find everything I need there ! Thanks again Daniel